# Optional Character is not getting removed even after optional binding

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, option-type, optional-binding

I am setting a optional property from previous view controller while pushing but even after optional binding its printing optional character in console. Here is my code

```
if let otp = self.confirmationCode {
    print(otp)        
}
```

It give output as follows:

```
"Optional(460207)"
```

What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: What is `confirmationCode`?

Comment: its a property I am setting while coming from another controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are properly unwrapping the optional value.

So if you still find `Optional...` in the output `String`, my guess is the original value `self.confirmationCode` does contain this text `Optional(460207)`.

This means you also need to unwrap the value somewhere else.